# Definition of Upper/Lower Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ of the real numbers, $\mathbb R$, and

$\mathcal P = \left \{[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],\dots,[x_{n-1},x_n] \right \}$,

be partition of the closed interval $[a,b]$, where

$ a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b $.

One, perhaps *the*, way of defining the Riemann upper sum is as follows.

$ U = \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i^*)\, \Delta x_i }$

where $ \Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1} $, $ x_i^*\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$, and $f(x_i^*) = \sup f([x_{i-1},x_i]) $ (that is, the supremum of $f$ over $[x_{i-1},x_i]$).

My question is how does this work for a function with a discontinuity at what would be it's maximum in a particular sub-interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$; say the function $f$ has a `hole' at the point $c\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$?

For example, take $f(x) = -x^2 + 1$ on $[-1,1]$ with $(0,1)$ removed, and consider a partition with one of the sub-intervals $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, $\epsilon >0$. In this situation, what value do you pick for the $x^*$ value in the sub-interval? I mean, it's clear that you'd take a rectangle of height 1 for this bin, since that is the supremum of the set of values of $f$ on this interval, but what value do you take for $x^*$? Does it matter, since the supremum for the set doesn't depend on the chosen value for $x^*$?

I think my misunderstand is how to interpret choosing an $x^*_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ when we are really using the supremum of the set of values of $f$ on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Does it matter which value we pick for $x_i^*$, since the supremum of the set is fixed?

Comment: By Riemann upper sum, do you mean Darboux upper sum.

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous on $[a,b]$, it is usually defined as $\sum M_i\Delta x_i$, with $M_i$ the supremum over the relevant interval; and $\sum m_i\Delta x_i$ with $m_i$ the infimum. You can show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ you can pick $x_i^*$ so that the sum you define is within $\epsilon$ of this number.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Perhaps, but I think they are equivalent, right?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since we are using the sup/inf does it matter which value we pick for $x_i^*$, as long as it is in the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$? That is, even though it's written $f(x^*_i)$, is the supremum $\textrm{sup }f([x_{i-1},x_i])$ really dependent on the choice of $x_i^*$?

Comment: I don’t understand your question: if the supremum is achieved, what you want is the value of the supremum. If it is achieved at more than one point, then it doesn’t matter which point you pick: the sum is still the same, because you are using the **value** of the function.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To me it doesn't seem like $\textrm{sup } f([x_{i-1},x_i])$ depends on a choice of $x_i^* \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$, as the supremum in my example doesn't belong to the set of values of $f$ on the particular sub-interval. So, for that particular sub-interval, can I choose any $x^* \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ (since I must pick a value for $x^*$ according to the definition of the Riemann sum).

Comment: You have things backwards. $x_i^*$ is chosen so that $f(x_i^*)$ is *equal* to $\sup(f[x_{i-1},x_i])$; such an $x_i^*$ exists if $f$ is continuous, because a continuous function defined on a finite closed interval always achieves its supremum/maximum. You can’t choose “any” $x_i^*$ for the upper sum, because not all $x_i^*$ will have $f(x_i^*)$ *equal* to the maximum value $f$ takes on the subinterval. Again, I fail to understand why you are confused about this.,

Comment: If your function $f$ is not continuous, then you don’t have a guarantee that such an $x_i^*$ exists; in that case, you define the upper sum as I indicated, expliicitly using $\sup(f[x_i,x_{i+1}])$; that is not a Riemann sum, though, because Riemann sums requires you to pick an $x_i^*$ in the interval. So, *as I said*, in that case you can show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a Riemann sum (a choice of $x_i^*$ for each subinterval) which is within $\epsilon$ of the upper sum.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But, my function is not continuous, and does not have a maximum for the sub-interval $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$. So there is not value $x^*\in [ -\epsilon, \epsilon]$ such that $f(x^*) = \textrm{sup } f ( [ -\epsilon, \epsilon] )$.

We have $\textrm{sup }f ( [ -\epsilon, \epsilon] ) = 1$, but $f(0)$ is undefined. Which value do I take for $x^*$ in this sub-inteval?


Edit (After reading you last comment): I thought that the Riemann upper sum is defined for all bounded functions on a closed interval. Is that not true?

Comment: Exactly how many times do I need to say the same thing? If the function is not continuous, the upper sum is *not* a Riemann sum: there is no $x_i^*$ to choose (or, there may not be).  But you can show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there *is* a Riemann sum which is within $\epsilon$ of the upper sum. Because if $M_i=\sup f[(x_i,x_{i+1}])$, then there must exist $x_i^*\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ such that $M_i-\frac{\epsilon}{n}\lt f(x_i^*)\leq M_i$, and you can do that for each subinterval.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is Wikipedia wrong then? It is not assumed that the function be continuous, only bounded. The ``Riemann Upper Sum'' is also defined the same way in my Apostol book.

Comment: One simple way to avoid this problem is use discontinuity points as interval breakpoints.  Then the question becomes moot.

Comment: As I said from the very beginning: “It is **usually** defined… `blah`”. There are not “right” or “wrong” definitions. There are definitions that have issues that need to be dealt with and issues that don’t. In the case of Wikipedia, you again have things backwards. What Wikipedia states is that **if** the choice of $x_i^*$ is such that $f(x_i^*)=\sup f[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, **then** the resulting sum is called an “Upper Riemann Sum”. It does **not** say that you can *always* define an upper Riemann Sum (in their nomenclature). If there is no choice that works, then there is no Upper Riemann Sum.

Comment: So what Wikipedia says is: **if** you always pick the left endpoint, what you get is called “the left Riemann sum”. **if** you always pick the right endpoint, then what you get is called “the right Riemann sum”. **If** you pick the midpoint, then what you get is called “the middle Riemann sum”. Those always exist. **If** you (are able to) pick $x_i^*$ so $f(x_I^*)$ is the supremum/maximum value of $f$, then what you get is called the “Upper Riemann Sum”. There is no assertion that it exists for every function and every partition, though. Under those definitions, it doesn’t.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I want to agree with you, but in a problem that I am reading online it specifically says that one can define the Riemann upper sum in the case that the function is defined on the closed interval. Does the Riemann upper sum depend on the chosen partition? Is the statement in the problem wrong?

Thank you for being so patient with me.

Comment: The Riemann Upper sum **always** depends on the choice of partition. If it didn’t, then it would always take the same value regardless of partition, which would make it useless. I am not responsible for on-line problems, which may be using other definitions or which may have standing assumptions that you have missed. Contact the person writing the online problem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the explanations! So, to make sure I understand, one cannot define a Riemann Upper Sum for the function $ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      -x^2 + 1 & x \neq 0, \\
      \tfrac{1}{2} & x = 0
   \end{cases} $ on the interval $[-1,1]$. But, they could for $ g(x)  = \begin{cases} 
      -x^2 + 1 & x \neq 0, \\
      2 & x = 0
   \end{cases} $ on the same interval. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are having some confusion on Riemann sum, Upper Darboux sum, Lower Darboux sum.

Based on Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*, I provide the following definitions which are pretty standard and followed in many other textbooks.

Let $[a, b] $ be a closed interval and let function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be bounded on $[a, b] $. A *partition* $P$ of $[a, b] $ is a finite set of points from interval $[a, b] $ and necessarily includes the end points. Typically  partition $P$ is written as $$P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\} $$ where $$a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n=b$$ Let us define $$M_k=\sup\, \{f(x) \mid x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\},k=1,2,\dots,n$$ and $$m_k=\inf\, \{f(x) \mid x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\}, k=1,2,\dots,n$$ Since $f$ is bounded the numbers $M_k, m_k$ exist. Also since we are *not* given that $f$ is continuous, these values $M_k, m_k$ may or may not be attained by $f$.

The upper Darboux sum for $f$ over partition $P$ of $[a, b] $, denoted by $U(f, P) $, is defined as $$U(f, P) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$$ In a similar manner the lower Darboux sum $L(f, P) $ is defined as $$L(f, P) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$$ Riemann sums are a bit more complicated in the sense that they not only depend upon the partition, but also on a further chosen set of points called *tags*.

Let $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n$ be points in $[a, b] $ such that $t_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$ for each $k$ and let $$T_P=\{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\}$$ The notation $T_P$ is used to emphasize that tag points are chosen based on a given partition.

A Riemann sum for $f$ over partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ with tag points in $T_P$, denoted by $S(f, P, T_P) $, is defined as $$S(f, P, T_P) =\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$$

Notice that for any partition $P$ and any tag set $T_P$ we have $$L(f, P) \leq S(f, P, T_P) \leq U(f, P) $$ because $m_k\leq f(t_k) \leq M_k$. Also we can choose the tag points $t_k$ such that $f(t_k) $ is close to $M_k$ (or $m_k$) and hence any upper or lower Darboux can be well approximated by a suitable Riemann sum.

More formally (and try to prove it) if $\epsilon>0$ then we can choose tag sets $T_P, T'_P$ such that $$U(f,P) - \epsilon <S(f, P, T_P) \leq U(f, P), \\ L(f,P) \leq S(f, P, T'_P) <L(f, P)+\epsilon $$ The equality in $\leq $ of these relations given above may or may not occur. In the special case of continuous $f$ such an equality is possible for suitable choice of tags.

Thus you should not try to express an upper Darboux sum as a Riemann sum. They are different but related concepts and it may not be possible to express one as another.

---

**Note**: The term *Riemann upper sum* is not standard and most probably being used in place of the standard term *upper Darboux sum*.

Comment: Also, it can be proven that both-Riemann sum and Darboux sum are equivalent that is, a function is Darboux integrable if and only if it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Koro: the inequalities in this answer are the key to the equivalence you mention.